What are my options if an open source project rejects my changes?
My employer recently joined an open source project and began making contributions to it. Some developers within my company have suggested changes that benefit our use cases but the upstream open source project does not want to accept the changes. What are our options for moving forward in this case?

Do we put our proverbial tail between our legs, abandon the use-case and the code change and move on?
Do we permanently fork the code?
Something else?


What kind of changes are these? Are they small localized changes just for you?

The change is a new, minor feature. The change will be beneficial for our use-case, but may or may not be as beneficial for general use-cases.

The first thing to do is figure out why the contributions are being rejected. There are several reasons why the upstream project could be rejecting the contributions.
One possibility is that the project has a process for suggesting and vetting ideas before including changes that must be followed. In this case, you can learn what you need to do to propose ideas and attempt to get buy-in before making technical contributions.
Another possibility is that the changes don't align with the maintainers' vision for the project. If this is the case, there's probably not much you can do to get your contributions accepted. In this case, you may need to fork the project to implement them.
A third possibility is technical. Perhaps the contributions don't meet the technical standards or conventions of the project. Some projects maintain guidance for contributors, which is a good place to start understanding the expectations.
Once you understand why the contributions are being rejected, you can better plan your next steps.
